# How to change href using <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I am trying to change the href of an id after 400 milliseconds in a script, but when I go to the page, after 400 the link is still the same.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(3).href=
    '/cgi-bin/mancalaV9eam.cgi/retro/2/3/1/4/4/4/0/5/5/1/5/4/4/4/4/4/0';}, 400);
</script>
```

Comment: do you have any errors in the console... is `3` really the ID, or is it `"3"`?

Comment: An ID is a String, so it needs to be wrapped with quotes, and it cannot start with a number (It can, but it's not valid)

Comment: Please show the HTML

Comment: create an anchor tag element. change its href property when needed. Also, '3' is not an ID as pointed out by others.

Comment: I currently have <img id=7 ...>
When I run a different script (change the image) the id works just fine, without the quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `id` of an element is a string, therefore you need to wrap the id inside the call to `getElementById` in quotes.

```js
 setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("3").href=
    '/cgi-bin/mancalaV9eam.cgi/retro/2/3/1/4/4/4/0/5/5/1/5/4/4/4/4/4/0';}, 400);
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" id="3">Does this still go to google?</a>
```

As pointed out in comments, `id` should usually not start with a numeric, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Document.getElamentById requires a [case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element being sought](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

So you need to pass it a string, but it's not clear exactly what the 3 in your script is referring to.